# How to ask questions in German regarding persons and objects

Tags: question

There’s a distinctive difference between asking questions about people and objects in English:

> Who did you go with yesterday?
>   With what did you go to the party yesterday?

I know that it’s something similar in German and it involves *womit,* but I’m not quite sure. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: search for an explanation on da-words. The wo-words are the question equivalent

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand a thing you just said.

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzglied/Objekt/Praepositional.html?lang=en and: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/da-words-meaning-german/ and: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/wo-compounds-worauf-woraus-wovon-meaning-german/

Answer (score 2):

The difference you are referring to is probably *Womit ... ?* vs. *Mit wem ... ?*

To ask for a person-object use *mit wem*. To ask for a thingy-object use *womit*.

For Example:

> Mit wem warst du gestern bei der Party? (Wer war dabei?)

vs.

> Womit warst du gestern bei der Party? (Was war dabei?)

Comment: Thanks, that's it I believe. 

Is this question right? 

Mit wem geht sie in der Diskothek?

Comment: and how to ask a question: 

When does he sleep? if you don't mind answering

Comment: @warwick : 1. Yes and no. It's "die Discothek". 2. "Wann schläft er?"  But please keep in mind that we are no translation service. Even Google translator could have got this right.